# About calculation of marginalizing (Bishop's book)

Tags: conditional-probability, marginal-distribution

I'd like to ask a simple question, but I don't know how to solve it. Basically, it is from Bishop's book *pattern recognition*. The following figure is from his book.

[image]

In chapter 8, to show that a and b are independent, he marginalizes the following equation over c,

$p(a,b) = p(a)\Sigma_{c}p(c|a)p(b|c) = p(a)p(b|a)$

I know that marginalizing over c means that

(suppose $c\in\{0, 1\}$)

$\Sigma_{c}p(c|a)p(b|c) = p(c=0|a)p(b|c=0) + p(c=1|a)p(b|=0)$

And then, how can I finish up deriving $p(b|a)$ from given equation?

---

**Updated:**

Okay,

$\Sigma_{c}p(c|a)p(b|c)$ will be $\Sigma_{c}p(b|c)$

Then, where "a" comes from in $p(b|a)$???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Sigma_{c}p(c|a)p(b|c) = \Sigma_{c}p(c|a)p(b|c,a)$ which is actually the definition of $p(b|a)$. Here, $p(b|c) = p(b|c,a)$ because based on your Bayesian NW figure, conditioned on $c$, $b$ and $a$ are independent.  To sum up, $a$ and $b$ are not independent, they're conditionally independent given $c$. By the way, your equation in the update part seems to be wrong.

Comment: I might be missing something but, if conditioned on $c$, $b$ and $a$ are independent you then would have $p(b|c,a) = p(b|c) \neq p(b|a)p(b|c)$.

Comment: $p(b,a)$ is the end of my sentence. Now I'm inserting a word in-between

Comment: Thanks, @gunes. Firstly, I should say sorry that I didn't write clearly. Bishop tried to show that a and b are independent conditioned on c. But if I didn't misunderstand your answer, you have already assumed that conditioned on c, b and a are independent. I will attach the part of proof again.